# Visual Studio 2013 Dataset Designer Does Not Match Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tableadapter, dataset-designer

I am having a problem with the Dataset Designer in VS2013.  I don't know how it happened but when I go to view a Dataset in the designer, a ton of my queries and stored procedures are missing. It's almost like the designer rolled back to defaults or something. I check the Designer.cs file and everything is there but now I can't use the designer at all.  I'm afraid that one of these times when closing the designer I'll accidentally click and hit a key when the prompt comes up asking if I want to save changes, and poof all my hard work is over written and destroyed(I have backups but still...).  Here is a question that seemed similar to my issue: [VS2008 DataSet Wizard doesn't match tables for updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068225/vs2008-dataset-wizard-doesnt-match-tables-for-updating)

The problem for this poster was a table got renamed or something.  I haven't renamed any of the tables as far as I know. Has anyone run into this before? How do I refresh the designer so it reflects the current content in my code(Designer.cs file) like queries and stored procedures? Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this but have been so slammed at work I haven't posted till right now.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx) is a link to a blog post describing how to clear the visual studio cache.  PLEASE BE CAUTIOUS and read carefully.  This worked for me and hopefully you too!